# Access to property apicontroller with reflection

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, system.reflection

i have a api-rest with many controllers with attribute: [ApiController], i need to access with reflection to controller and view if this controller have this attribute. How could I do that? thanks

Comment: Hi @David,Did my answer help you resolve your issue?

Comment: hi @Rena, yes i resolve this problem with your solution, thanks

Comment: If my answer helped you,could you accept as answer?Refer to:[How to accept as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you all non-abstract controllers in your currently executing assembly inheriting from the `ControllerBase` and implementing `ApiControllerAttribute`. If you want to move some of the conditions or target different assembly, feel free to do so.

```
IEnumerable<Type> controllerTypes = Assembly
    .GetExecutingAssembly()
    .GetTypes()
    .Where(type => type.IsClass
        && !type.IsAbstract
        && type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(ControllerBase))
        && type.GetCustomAttribute<ApiControllerAttribute>() != null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following code to check if the specific controller have `ApiController` attribute:

```
var flag = typeof(ValuesController).GetTypeInfo()
                                    .GetCustomAttribute(typeof(ApiControllerAttribute));
if(flag!=null)
{
     //ValuesController have the ApiController attribute
     //do your stuff...
}
```